# convert a row to multiple lines after every 6th space

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, sed

I have text like below

```
Current state of abc : RUNNING Current state of def : RUNNING Current state of ghi : RUNNING
```

I want this single line to be split into multiple rows like below

```
Current state of abc : RUNNING 
Current state of def : RUNNING 
Current state of ghi : RUNNING
```

I tried with tr command like `tr ' ' '\n'` , but it prints the row after every space.

Comment: Do all the output lines start with "Current"?

Comment: The tags "bash" and "shell" are generally mutually exclusive. Please read descriptions of tags that you apply!

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Thus, I'm surprised that you don't also find the [unix] tag redundant with regard to [shell], [awk] and [sed].

Comment: That's correct, @Kaz, the behaviour of the tools should be the same whether on Unix or any other system, so it's not about Unix-specific behaviour or API.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Continuing with the `tr` thought:

```bash
tr -s ' ' '\n' | paste -d ' ' - - - - - -
# or, handle tabs too
tr -s '[:space:]' '\n' | paste -d ' ' - - - - - -
```

Or sed, inserting a newline after every 6 words

```bash
sed -E 's/([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){6}/&\n/g'
```

The same idea in perl

```bash
perl -pe 's/(\S+\s+){6}/$&\n/g'
```

or GNU grep for `-o` and `\S/\s`:

```bash
grep -Eo '(\S+\s+){5}\S+'
```

or GNU awk for multi-char `RS` and `RT` and `\S/\s`:

```bash
awk -v RS='(\\S+\\s+){5}\\S+' 'RT{print RT}'
```

Comment: The `(\S+\s+){6}`s will print spaces at the end of the first 2 output lines which may be undesirable vs `(\S+\s+){5}\S+` which won't do that. Hope you don't mind me adding grep and awk alternatives, feel free to rollback (with my apologies) if you do, just didn't feel right to add another answer so similar.

Comment: Perhaps for a sed solution:  `sed 's/ /\n/6;P;D' file`? or for tr and paste: `tr ' ' '\n' <file|paste -sd'     \n'`

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -v RS=" " '{ printf("%s%s", $0, (NR % 6) ? " " : "\n") }'
```

Treat single spaces as strict record separators. Thus every word becomes an Awk record rather than field. We print every record. If it isn't every sixth record, we print a space after it. If it is every sixth record, we print a newline after it.

Answer (score 1):

Using any version of `awk`. With your shown samples in `awk` you could try following. Using regex `(^| )(\S+\s){5}\S+(\s|$)` here to tackle the problem here.

```
awk '
{
  while(match($0,/(^| )(\S+\s){5}\S+(\s|$)/)){
    val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
    sub(/ $/,"",val)
    print val
    $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  }
}
' Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
Current state of abc : RUNNING Current state of def : RUNNING Current state of ghi : RUNNING
```

then

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=1){printf("%s%s",$i,i%6?OFS:ORS)}}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
Current state of abc : RUNNING
Current state of def : RUNNING
Current state of ghi : RUNNING
```

**Disclaimer**: this solution assumes number of fields in each line is always evenly divisible by 6, it this is not case do not use it. Explanation: I iterate over fields in line using `for` loop, I print value of field (`$i`) followed by output field separator (default: space) if number of column is not evenly divisible by 6 (i.e. remainder from division by 6 is not zero) else output row separator (default: newline). I use `printf` rather than `print` as former does not automatically add tralining newline.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)*